# how do I add unary operator for RPN algorithm that calculates postfix expression in java

Tags: java, unary-operator, rpn

I have to create an application which calculates postfix expressions. I was able to find it online ([rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm#Java_2)) but it's missing a unary operator. the symbol "~" is supposed to denote the unary operator I tried adding it but unfortunately it didn't work. Please advise;

```
else if(token.equals("~")){
            System.out.print("Operate\t\t");
            double firstOperand = stack.pop();
            stack.push(firstOperand * -1);
}else
```

Comment: "didn't work" deserves an answer like "correct it". A bit more information could help to help. Anyway: negate for **double** would be just `-firstOperand`, no need to use any method of Math. BTW  why are you getting **two** values from the stack, only one is needed.

Comment: You will create intrinsic ambiguity if you try and use the same symbol ('-') for binary subtraction and unary negation.

Comment: Hey Carlos, like dave said I have to make a distinction. Also reverse polish notation is rather confusing but what you're saying is to write it like this "stack.push(firstOperand * -1);"

Comment: I just edited it, and I believe its working but I honestly don't know the postfix is  (7 5 3 - - ~~~) and the final answer I get is -5.

Comment: 3-5 = -2, -7 = -9, with three sign reversals = +9. So something is already wrong with your subtraction code. Note that the operands come off the stack in the wrong order for subtract and divide as written in infix.

Answer (score 0):

The unary `~` is undefined for double values. So its not recommended to support the operator in the following way:

```
  …
  try {
    tokenNum = Double.parseDouble( token );
  }
  catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
    if( token.startsWith( "~" ) ) {
      tokenNum = (double) ~ Integer.parseInt( token.substring( 1 ) );
      token = tokenNum.toString();
    }
  }
  …

  return( expr.replaceAll( "[^\\^\\*\\~\\+\\-\\d/\\s]", "" ) );  // cleanExpr
```

For this reason the RPN language [7th](https://www.7th-stone.com/) does not support the unary `~`. You must call eg. `2 not` in place of `~2`.

Comment: I tried using your solution but it stops as soon as it gets to the unary operator ~.

Comment: He is using `~` to mean unary minus, not complement. Read the question. And don't answer twice.

Answer (score 0):

nothing is stopping with aforementioned changes in the [rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm#Java_2)

```
evalRPN( "~3 ~4 ~2 * ~1 ~5 - ~2 ~3 ^ ^ / +" );
```

gives

```
Input   Operation   Stack after
~3  Push        [-4.0]
~4  Push        [-5.0, -4.0]
~2  Push        [-3.0, -5.0, -4.0]
*   Operate     [15.0, -4.0]
~1  Push        [-2.0, 15.0, -4.0]
~5  Push        [-6.0, -2.0, 15.0, -4.0]
-   Operate     [4.0, 15.0, -4.0]
~2  Push        [-3.0, 4.0, 15.0, -4.0]
~3  Push        [-4.0, -3.0, 4.0, 15.0, -4.0]
^   Operate     [0.012345679012345678, 4.0, 15.0, -4.0]
^   Operate     [1.017262041564032, 15.0, -4.0]
/   Operate     [14.745463201337605, -4.0]
+   Operate     [10.745463201337605]
Final answer: 10.745463201337605
```

same result as in [7th](https://www.7th-stone.com)

```
ok> 3 not 4 not 2 not * 1 not 5 not - 2 not 3 not y^x y^x / +
ok> .s
› 10,7454632
——
```

Comment: He is using `~` to mean unary minus, not complement. Read the question. And don't answer twice.

Comment: [_"unary minus" is the name for the symbol in *-a*_](https://unlearningmath.com/2009/05/26/notes-on-operations-unary-minus/)